# %& magic line has no effect

Tags: plain-tex

I am using the %&format magic line in a plain TeX file. On older versions of TeX the result produces the expected results. On TeXLive 2009 (under Gentoo), however, this line has no effect. When I use 'tex -fmt format.fmt file.tex' the expected font substitutions nevertheless work. Has the magic file feature to be enabled in some config file? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Gentoo, but this is controlled by the `parse_first_line` option. For me, it lives in `/.../texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`. That said, changes should go in `/.../texlive/2010/texmf.cnf`:

```
parse_first_line = t
```

Comment: or use command line option [-no]-parse-first-line

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the speedy reply. In Gentoo the file is /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf. In there, parse_first_line was set true by default, but parse_first_line.tex was set to false. Changing to true ('t') fixed the problem. Great help!

Comment: You should add that as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @TH: I don't think he has the rep to do that yet.

Comment: By the way, Michael, it is probably a good idea to associate an openid with your account in case you lose the cookie. (Assuming, of course, that you have not already lost it.)