# using texlive:latex/pdflatex/xelatex and shebang (jobname)

Tags: miktex, jobname

I'm wondering, why my minimal example (in file `shebang.tex`)

```
%& -job-name=test
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hidiho
\end{document}
```

will always (no matter if using `latex`, `pdflatex` oder `xelatex`) compile to `shebang.dvi/pdf` and not to `test.dvi/pdf`. Are shebang-lines deactivated?

Edit: I just found out, that it is something with encoding: Using MikTex in Windows on the file encoded in `ISO-8859-15` it is working - but not with encoding `UTF-8` - which I like to use.
Under Debian Linux with texlive, no matter which encoding it is not working.
Maybe one needs another symbol after the percent-symbol?
The questions seems to be somehow related to [%& magic line has no effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/magic-line-has-no-effect): But there is also a difference: Running the command `xelatex -parse-first-line shebang` will also produce `shebang.pdf`. In the log file, there occur those lines

```
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**shebang
(./shebang.tex
\openout1 = `shebang.aux'.
```

showing the flag being recognized - but the job-name not working.

Comment: No idea if this is at all relevant, but that doesn't look like a regular percent-sign to me.

Comment: @wh1t3 please check this by copy and paste into one editor of your choice: For me this is the default one... - and I think further it is not really relevant.

Comment: Well, if I start writing an answer it looks different in the preview here. I wonder if it looks different if I just put one here: `%`. Edit: Yes, that looks different... Again, perhaps it's not related, I don't know how the shebang is checked, I can imagine that if it's some unicode character and not "really" a percent sign (ASCII character 37), this would cause issues...

Comment: @wh1t3 this is really strange: in my browsers (chrome on win/iceweasel on debian) it looks the same... I agree with your imagination depending on the "maybe different" percent signs... please have a look at my further edit above...

Comment: Okay, from the link you edited into your question, it looks like it might have nothing to do with encoding, but some setting instead. Have you looked into the settings specified in that question?

Comment: @wh1t3, yes I did by trying the command line. I added the result to the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2346/discussion-between-bastian-ebeling-and-wh1t3)

Comment: where did you read that you can use other options than the format or a translate file for the use of `%&` ?

Comment: @Herbert - good question: Maybe I read that long ago - or I just tried out and it worked... (Maybe only on MikTeX/Windows? but only with ISO-encoding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MikTeX documentation specifies the `%&` option can be used to add additional command line parameters. It uses `miktex-pdftex` though, instead of just `pdftex`. The [`pdflatex` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdflatex) suggests the `%&` option can only be used for format files and `-translate-file` options.

> `-parse-first-line`
>
> If the first line of the main input file begins with `%&` parse it to look for a dump name or a `-translate-file` option.

You could of course write your own wrapper script that parses the first line and then calls `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or your engine of choice with the suggested parameters. I am guessing this is basically what `miktex-pdftex` does.