# The role of %&latex at the beginning of a source latex file

Tags: tex-core, format-files

Could someone please explain what is the role of `%&latex` which is put in a source LaTeX file before `\begin{document}` command?

Comment: @egreg Maybe you could point to some on-line material concerning the issue?

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42893/using-texlivelatex-pdflatex-xelatex-and-shebang-jobname

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In olden times, TeX came in two incarnations: `initex` and `virtex`. The first binary was used to *create* formats such as Plain and LaTeX, the second one was used for typesetting documents after loading one of the available formats.

So one had to do

```
initex lplain
```

and save the created file `lplain.fmt` in some suitable directory; from then on, it was possible to typeset a document with

```
virtex '&lplain' file
```

Of course many users or system administrators defined aliases, so that one could simply call

```
latex file
```

During the years several tricks for easing the choice of formats were devised. For instance, some systems made a memory dump of `initex` instead of doing `\dump`, so the dump could be turned into an executable, so speeding up the start of the run.

Another trick was to allow TeX to parse the first line of the first input file, so if the file was

```
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The Mad Hatter and the White Hare.
\end{document}
```

a simple call

```
tex file
```

would have been equivalent to `tex '&latex' file`. Yes, in more recent times, instead of `virtex` the executable was being called `tex` and the format for LaTeX was being created with `initex latex.ltx`, so the format produced was `latex.fmt`.

This “first line parsing” is available also with current TeX distributions. I'm not sure what's the status of MiKTeX (what I know is that it allows more options to be specified).

The TeX Live distribution uses a different strategy; when a format is created (using the script `mktexfmt-sys`), say for `pdflatex`, a symbolic link

```
pdftex -> pdflatex
```

is created in the binary directory; this is what I have on my system:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  6 Apr 20  2013 /usr/texbin/pdflatex@ -> pdftex
```

This makes `pdflatex` into an “executable”, but `pdftex` is actually run; the program has the ability of knowing what name it has been called with, and do the appropriate action when loading the format.

So, what happens if you have the file above and run the command line

```
pdflatex file
```

without any other option? The “first line parsing” is active, so this overrides the format choice based on the calling name and the `latex` format is chosen, which produces its output in DVI format rather than PDF.

So, the best thing is *not* to use the first line in that format. It's confusing, at the least.

You can look at the documentation of TeX Live, for more information:

http://texdoc.net./texmf/doc/texlive/texlive-en/texlive-en.pdf

discovering that the option is not even described. The man page for pdftex has

> **`-parse-first-line`**
>   If the first line of the main input file begins with `%&` parse it to look for
>   a dump name or a `-translate-file` option.
>
> **`-no-parse-first-line`**
>   Disable parsing of the first line of the main input file.
>
> [...]
>
> **`-translate-file tcxname`**
>   Use the tcxname translation table to set the mapping of input characters and remapping of output characters. This feature can be useful if you have a personal special format and don't want to bother with creating aliases or symbolic links.

The TeX Live manual talks a bit about TCX files that are, however, a relic of the past, mainly.

The feature can be turned off at run time by calling

```
pdftex -no-parse-first-line
```

(any symbolic link pointing to `pdftex` can be used). Note that the feature is turned *off* by default when using `tex` (that is, the original Knuth TeX, not able to produce PDF output). The relevant settings in the standard `texmf.cnf` file are

```
% Allow TeX, and MF to parse the first line of an input file for
% the %&format construct.
parse_first_line = t

% But don't parse the first line if invoked as "tex", since we want that
% to remain Knuth-compatible.  The src_specials and
% file_line_error_style settings, as well as the options -enctex,
% -mltex, -8bit, etc., also affect this, but they are all off by default.
parse_first_line.tex = f
parse_first_line.initex = f
```

If you add

```
parse_first_line = f
```

to the top level `texmf.cnf` file, that is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf
```

for the 2013 release, you turn off the feature for all binaries.

Comment: [miktex-pdftex](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pdftex.html) has `--parse-first-line` and `--dont-parse-first-line` argument to verify or not read `%&` respectively

Comment: off-topic: surprising why texdoc.net link shows 2012 guide rather than [texdoc texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.pdf)

Comment: Also running `pdftex` on a file with `pdftex "\input" filename.tex` disables first line parsing.  AUCTeX does so, it should be remembered when compiling with `C-c C-c`.

Comment: @giordano Yes; only a letter makes TeX loading a file (and do the parsing of the first line); a command will immediately start TeXing.

Answer (score 5):

It makes `pdflatex` compile a DVI output. If you want to produce a PDF, just do one of the following:

- Change it to `%&pdflatex`
- Run `pdflatex -no-parse-first-line`
- Remove it.

Comment: One more question -- the command can take arguments, for example: %&latex --translate-file=cp1250t1. What is their role?

Comment: I *think* that argument is used to specify text encoding outside the document. That way, documents self-specify their encoding and do not need to use the `inputenc` package (which may produce some conflicts).