# What's the difference between terminal application of XeLaTex and XeTex?

Tags: xetex, terminal-output

On my Mac I wanted to create the PDF via terminal, and I found I cannot use `xetex filename.tex`, but `xelatex filename.tex` works just fine. I checked the file, `xelatex` is actually an alias pointed to `xetex`. But why they behave so different? I may need to use the original executable rather than alias to avoid exceptions.

Here's some output:

```
$ xetex Assignment\ 4.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xetex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Assignment 4.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \documentclass
              [a4paper, 11pt]{article} % Font size (can be 10pt, 11pt or...

? ^Z
[3]  + 44568 suspended  xetex Assignment\ 4.tex 


$ xelatex Assignment\ 4.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Assignment 4.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
...
```

Comment: On the command line, what are the outputs of `which xetex` and `which xelatex`? This indicates which program is actually executed.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64000/executables-of-formats-engines-and-executables-of-engines and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161042/the-role-of-latex-at-the-beginning-of-a-source-latex-file

Comment: @ArunDebray The same executable is used in each case. `which` does not tell you which programme is executed if the result is an alias.

Comment: What exceptions are you worried about exactly? Why would using the alias be a problem?

Comment: @ArunDebray If you try `ls -l $(which -p xelatex)` you'll see something like `/usr/texbin/xelatex@ -> xetex` in the output.

Comment: @egreg: do you mean `which -a xelatex`? I tried with `-p` and it said `Illegal option -p`. (I'm using TeXLive on Ubuntu, so perhaps things are different here.) I tried `which -a`, and for me, `xetex` and `xelatex` are different files.

Comment: @ArunDebray That's shell dependent, I guess.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I'm worry about if the alias is not available in some case. I want to use XeLaTeX to generate PDF in my future project. Then different machines may have some situations. :)

Comment: Hi @ArunDebray as comments made above, which itself doesn't tell you if that is an alias. I found it out by using "Get Info" in Finder. However `ls -l $(which -p xelatex)` works perfect for me on OS X. However, I didn't find anything about `-p` on `man which`. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @StarkShaw If the machine does not have `xelatex` in some form (alias or otherwise - not sure what Windows does) then you have more to worry about than needing to specify the format explicitly. Of course, it is *possible*. But it is also possible the machine won't have the LaTeX format or the `xetex` binary. If the machine has anything like a working installation of TeX which is not truly ancient, it will have `xelatex`.

Comment: @ArunDebray They are different files but only one is an executable. The other is a symbolic link to the executable. Try `ls -l $(which xelatex)`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your heads-up! :)

Comment: @egreg On my system, `which` is not shell-dependent. It is provided by a package called `which` and the manual includes stuff about both sh and csh style shells. No `-p`.

Comment: @StarkShaw Maybe Apple has doctored the command. Or there's a default configuration file for the shell setting `which` as an alias. (Which is also probably Apple doctoring the command.) I don't necessarily mean this is bad. All systems do it to some extent or other. But `-p` does not seem to be standard. Unless it is a BSD extension, which is also possible but then I'd expect a suitable man page.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I have it in my `.bashrc` (I don't remember from when).

Comment: Or @egreg doctoring the command.... But probably that is standard if it is the same for Stark Shaw ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XeTeX is the engine. LaTeX is the format. When you compile with `xetex`, the LaTeX format is not loaded so things like `\documentclass` are not defined. You can compile this way if your document is not using LaTeX but plain TeX.

The executable is the same, but the name you call it by matters. This is because the executable tests to find out what name it has been called by. If the answer is `xelatex`, it loads the LaTeX format and things like `\documentclass` are defined. You can see this early in the output where the console shows

```
... preloaded format=xelatex ...
```

If the answer is `xetex`, it does not load the LaTeX format and things like `\documentclass` are not defined.

```
... preloaded format=xetex ...
```

If you wish, you can use

```
xetex -fmt=<format>
```

and specify the format you want explicitly. However, in general, there's no reason to do that when an alias such as `xelatex` is available, although there's no harm in doing it either - the result will be the same.

Comment: @StarkShaw It is a little odd at first. But a rose by any other name is not always the same rose, even if it is equally sweet ;).