# Typeset handout under a different filename

Tags: pgfpages, handout

I have a latex document that I sometimes want to print in "handout" form, specifically four pages in one. I've been using

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}
```

in the preamble, thus printing 4 pages in one, which works just fine. By commenting out these commands in the preamble, I am able to typeset either the "normal" version of my file or the "handout" version.

My question: knowing that the source file's name is `filename.tex`, is there an easy way of typesetting into a pdf file called `filename_handout.pdf` rather than `filename.pdf`?

Currently, I need to go to the folder containing the output file `filename.pdf` and manually change the file name. I was hoping I could save that step since I need to create "handout" versions of many of my files.

In case it matters, I use TeXShop on a Mac (and I have MikTeX installed).

Comment: There are a variety of methods to achieve this.  Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5899/86 (and related questions) to see if any would be suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @LoopSpace for your suggestion. I followed the link you provided and various links in there. I was unable to find a solution that addresses the request above. The proposed solutions require working with several files or LaTeXing from the command line, none of which I want to do. The only solution that comes close to what I am looking for is to include in the preamble the command

```
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\jobname_handout\space\jobname}
```

This produces an output file `filename_handout.pdf` *in addition* to `filename.pdf` (assuming the source is `filename.tex`). I have not found a way of preventing `filename.pdf` from being created. Still, I find that this solution is better than nothing (and the alternatives I looked at). Specifically, by selectively commenting out the code

```
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=\jobname_handout\space\jobname}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}
```

in the preamble, I can toggle on and off the creation of a 4 in 1 handout. The only problem is that, when this code is on, typesetting it also creates the same handout in the file filename.pdf, so I always need to end the process by typesetting the document with the above commands commented out. In this way, I am able to produce two files, `filename.pdf` and `filename_handout.pdf`, *from a single source file*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you want your non-handout-document as **filename.pdf** and you want your handout-document as **filename_handout.pdf**.

Maintain both versions via the .tex-source file **filename.tex** but compile **filename.tex** only for obtaining the non-handout-document whose name will be **filename.pdf**:

```
% \providecommand does define a command only in case it is 
% not already defined.
\providecommand\Handoutmode{01}%<-Not in Handout-Mode

\newcommand\Handoutfork{}%    
\expandafter\let\expandafter\Handoutfork\expandafter=%
\csname @\if\Handoutmode first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname

\if\Handoutmode
  % load whatever you need for the handout but don't need for
  % the main document:
  \documentclass{article}
  \newcommand\DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand{handout}
\else
  % load whatever you need for the main document nut not for
  % the main document:
  \documentclass{article}
  \newcommand\DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand{main document}
\fi

\begin{document}

You are looking at the \DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand.

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\Handoutfork{This is Text that goes into the handout only.}%
            {This is Text that goes into the main document only.}

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\if\Handoutmode
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text in handout.
\end{verbatim}
\else
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text in main document.
\end{verbatim}
\fi

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\end{document}
```

For obtaining the handout as **filename_handout.pdf** maintain in the same folder/directory and compile another .tex-input file whose name is **filename_handout.tex** and whose content consists of two lines:

```
\providecommand\Handoutmode{00}%<-In Handout-Mode
\input filename.tex
```

With the two examples, **filename.pdf** will be:

[image]

And **filename_handout.pdf** will be:

[image]

---

Of course you can automatize the creating of **filename_handout.pdf** without an extra **filename_handout.tex** via `\write18`-calls to **filename.pdf** with option
`--job-name=\jobname_handout` (MiKTeX)  respective
`--jobname=\jobname_handout` (TeXLive).

When doing this, you can, e.g., evaluate whether the expansion of `\jobname` has a trailing phrase `_handout` and define your handout-forking-macros accordingly.

I did not see this proposition of evaluating `\jobname` in the other threads.

By the way:

As with each variant of the document you might need several LaTeX-runs for compiling it, while it isn't ensured that with each variant of the document you need the same amount of LaTeX-runs for compiling it, I would, in case of MiKTeX being available, not call the **pdflatex** -program but the **texify**-program with the `--pdf`-option and with passing on to the **pdflatex**-program the option `--job-name=\jobname_handout` via **texify**'s `--tex-option` as
`--tex-option="--job-name=\jobname_handout"`.

I would do that \write18-call to **texify** only during the first LaTeX-run on **filename.tex** when not in handout-mode.

Detecting the first LaTeX run can probably be done by checking the existence of the aux-file(s).

Here comes the code.

(If you wish, you can put some of the code into a package which you can load via `\RequirePackage` or via `\input` before forking what documentclass to use etc.)

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% The following lines could go into a separate package that is to be
% loaded via \input or (in case of also having package options)
% via \RequirePackage before writing any other preamble-thinglie like
% \documantclass...
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Check whether the current \jobname has a trailing phrase "_handout"
% and set \Handoutmde accordingly.
\begingroup
\makeatletter
%
\def\testA{_handout}%
\@onelevel@sanitize\testA
%
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\testB
\expandafter#\expandafter1\testA{}%
%
\edef\testA{%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter            \testB
  \expandafter\jobname
  \testA
}%
\def\testB{}%
\ifx\testA\testB
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\endgroup\providecommand\Handoutmode{01}}%<-Not in Handout-Mode
{\endgroup\providecommand\Handoutmode{00}}%<-In Handout-Mode

\newcommand\Handoutfork{}%    
\expandafter\let\expandafter\Handoutfork\expandafter=%
\csname @\if\Handoutmode first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname

% (If you put the code into a package by itself, you can create a
% package option for deciding whether to create or not to create
% the handout.)
%
% Create the handout:
\if\Handoutmode\else
% TeXLive-variant, without texify. Perhaps latexmk... Here the option is --jobname:
% \immediate\write18{pdflatex --jobname=\jobname_handout \jobname.tex}%
% MiKTeX-Variant, here the option is --job-name.:
\immediate\write18{pdflatex --job-name=\jobname_handout \jobname.tex}%
% With MiKTeX better might be:
% \IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{}{%
%   \immediate\write18{texify --pdf --clean --run-viewer --tex-option="--job-name=\jobname_handout" \jobname.tex}%
% }%
\fi
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% From here on, things cannot go into a separate package any
% more.
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\if\Handoutmode
  % load whatever you do need for the handout but do not need for
  % the main document:
  \documentclass{article}
  \newcommand\DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand{handout}
\else
  % load whatever you do need for the main document but do not need for
  % the main document:
  \documentclass{article}
  \newcommand\DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand{main document}
\fi

\begin{document}

You are looking at the \DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand.

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\Handoutfork{This is Text that goes into the handout only.}%
            {This is Text that goes into the main document only.}

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\if\Handoutmode
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text in handout.
\end{verbatim}
\else
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text in main document.
\end{verbatim}
\fi

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\end{document}
```

---

A starting point for a separate package **AddHandout** as mentioned above could be something like this—I decided to give the package a bizarre name because I do not intend to develop/maintain it any further and therefore I did not want to block a "good" package name:

**AddHandoutBizarrePackageName.sty**:

```
%% This is file `AddHandoutBizarrePackageName.sty',
%%
%% Copyright (C) 2018 by Ulrich Diez <ud.usenetcorrespondence@web.de>
%%
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3 of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version.  The latest version of this
%% license is in:
%%
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%%
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX version
%% 2003/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This file forms a "work" according to the terms of the 
%% LaTeX Project Public License.
%%
%% This "work" is not maintained.
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{AddHandoutBizarrePackageName}[2018/08/23 V.0.1beta -- A \write18-hook for handout-compilation]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

% Check whether the current \jobname has a trailing phrase "_handout"
% and set \Handoutmde accordingly.
\begingroup
%
\def\testA{_handout}%
\@onelevel@sanitize\testA
%
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\testB
\expandafter#\expandafter1\testA{}%
%
\edef\testA{%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter            \testB
  \expandafter\jobname
  \testA
}%
\def\testB{}%
%
\ifx\testA\testB
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\endgroup\providecommand\Handoutmode{01}}%<-Not in Handout-Mode
{\endgroup\providecommand\Handoutmode{00}}%<-In Handout-Mode
%
\newcommand\Handoutfork{}%    
\expandafter\let\expandafter\Handoutfork\expandafter=%
\csname @\if\Handoutmode first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
%
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=\@currname, prefix=\@currname @, setkeys=\kvsetkeys}
\DeclareStringOption[no_handout]{platform}[]%
\DeclareDefaultOption{\@unknownoptionerror}%
\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions{\@currname}%

\begingroup
\def\testA{Handout-MiKTeX-texify}%
\ifx\testA\AddHandoutBizarrePackageName@platform
  \if\Handoutmode\else
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{}{%
      \immediate\write18{texify --pdf --clean --run-viewer --tex-option="--job-name=\jobname_handout" \jobname.tex}%
    }%
  \fi
\else
  \def\testA{Handout-MiKTeX}%
  \ifx\testA\AddHandoutBizarrePackageName@platform
    \if\Handoutmode\else
      \immediate\write18{pdflatex --job-name=\jobname_handout \jobname.tex}%
    \fi
  \else
    \def\testA{Handout-TeXLive}%
    \ifx\testA\AddHandoutBizarrePackageName@platform
      \if\Handoutmode\else
        \immediate\write18{pdflatex --jobname=\jobname_handout \jobname.tex}%
      \fi
    \else
      \def\testA{no_handout}%
      \ifx\testA\AddHandoutBizarrePackageName@platform
      \else
        \def\testA{}%
        \ifx\testA\AddHandoutBizarrePackageName@platform
          \PackageWarningNoLine{\@currname}{%
             You need tp specify a value for the option "platform". 
             Handout will not be created%
          }%
        \else
          \PackageWarningNoLine{\@currname}{%
            The platform '\AddHandoutBizarrePackageName@platform'
            is unknown. Handout will not be created%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
\endgroup

\endinput
```

You can load the package via \RequirePackage before writing any other component
of the preamble.

For forking depending on whether currently producing the handout or the main document,

```
\if\Handoutmode .. \else .. \fi
```

and

```
 \Handoutfork{This is Text that goes into the handout only.}%
             {This is Text that goes into the main document only.}%
```

are available.

If you load the package without any option, only the file **⟨filename⟩.pdf** but no no file **⟨filename⟩_handout.pdf** will be produced.

If you load the package with option "platform=Handout-MiKTeX-texify", the file **⟨filename⟩.pdf** will be produced and it will be attempted to produce **⟨filename⟩_handout.pdf** by means of "\write18`-calls suitable for the **texify**-program of the TeX-Distribution "MiKTeX".

If you load the package with option "platform=Handout-MiKTeX", the file **⟨filename⟩.pdf** will be produced and it will be attempted to produce **⟨filename⟩_handout.pdf** by means of "\write18`-calls suitable for the **pdflatex**-program of the TeX-Distribution "MiKTeX".

If you load the package with option "platform=Handout-TeXLive", the file **⟨filename⟩.pdf** will be produced and it will be attempted to produce **⟨filename⟩_handout.pdf** by means of "\write18`-calls suitable for the **pdflatex**-program of the TeX-Distribution "TeXLive".

This way you can within one single `\RequirePackage`-line of the document specify if you wish to also obtain a handout.
Besides this you have facilities for both in the preamble and in the document forking depending on whether currently the main document or the handout is typeset.

Usage-example, e.g., **filename.tex**

```
%      Produce only <filename>.pdf, no <filename>_handout.pdf:
%\RequirePackage{AddHandoutBizarrePackageName}
%      Produce only <filename>.pdf, no <filename>_handout.pdf:
%\RequirePackage[platform=no_handout]{AddHandoutBizarrePackageName}%
%      Produce <filename>.pdf and try to produce <filename>_handout.pdf 
%      via \write18 calls suitable for MiKTeX' texify:
\RequirePackage[platform=Handout-MiKTeX-texify]{AddHandoutBizarrePackageName}
%      Produce <filename>.pdf and try to produce <filename>_handout.pdf 
%      via \write18 calls suitable for MiKTeX' pdflatex:
%\RequirePackage[platform=Handout-MiKTeX]{AddHandoutBizarrePackageName}
%      Produce <filename>.pdf and try to produce <filename>_handout.pdf 
%      via \write18 calls suitable for TeXLive' pdflatex:
%\RequirePackage[platform=Handout-TeXLive]{AddHandoutBizarrePackageName}

\if\Handoutmode
  % load whatever you do need for the handout but do not need for
  % the main document:
  \documentclass{article}
  \newcommand\DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand{handout}
\else
  % load whatever you do need for the main document but do not need for
  % the handout:
  \documentclass{article}
  \newcommand\DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand{main document}
\fi

\begin{document}

You are looking at the \DifferingBehaviorBetweenMainDocumentAndHandoutCommand.

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\Handoutfork{This is Text that goes into the handout only.}%
            {This is Text that goes into the main document only.}

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\if\Handoutmode
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text in handout.
\end{verbatim}
\else
\begin{verbatim}
Verbatim text in main document.
\end{verbatim}
\fi

This is text that is both in the main document and in the handout.

\end{document}
```

---

In any case you use the same .tex-input-code for creating different variants of a document.

Be aware that you need to pay special attention in case the .tex-input-code is also used for having something done where randomness plays a role.

E.g., having via `\pgfrandom` created some numbers at random and henceforth having LaTeX use these random numbers within the document that is about to be created.

When compiling the one variant of the document, the random-number-generator might produce random values that differ from those produced by the random-number-generator when compiling the other variant of the document. Thus in such a scenario the content of the two documents might not be identical any more. ...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @UlrichDiez. @LoopSpace also links to a variety of solutions that are based on the idea of having multiple source files as you suggest. What would be really neat is to have a system whereby you can produce a `filename.pdf` file or `filename_handout.pdf` file from the same source file, simply by toggling on and off some text in the preamble. For this to happen, the only thing that I am missing is ***to change the pdf output file name from within the tex source file***

Comment: @LMBC Searching on this site, my conclusion is that it is impossible to change the pdf file name from within the tex source.  By the time the tex source starts being parsed, the pdf file name is set and cannot be changed.

Comment: @LoopSpace In this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the) masu claims that it can be done, but I could not get this to work, even when typesetting from the command line.

Comment: @LMBC I have now edited my answer and added an example where both filename.pdf and filename_handout.pdf will be created from the same source without an additional .tex-input file. But you need `\write18`-feature. You said you have MiKTeX. If you have MiKTeX' texify available I would do a `\write18`-call on texify rather than on the pdflatex-program. Details in the that part of my answer that I have just added. With the example, **<jobname>_handout.pdf** will be created in any case. Of course you can nest the `\writ18`-call into something like `\IfIWantHandout..\else..\fi`.

Comment: @LoopSpace Yes: It is impossible to change the pdf-file from within a latex-run. Redefining `\jobname` does not change file-names but just turn `\jobname` from the primitive into some macro... But using `\write18` you can call LaTeX again, on the most TeX-platforms with some jobname-option for telling it what names to use for creating .log-file, .pdf-file, .aux-files etc...

Comment: @LMBC I just eddited my answer once more to make sure the mechanisms shown in the last example also work out without eTeX-extensions...

Comment: @LMBC Reading around, that *might* work with miktex, but not with any other variant of tex.  See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161042/86

Comment: @UlrichDiez If I understand correctly, your edited answer does the same as my answer with the difference that you created an `\if` statement whereas I just comment out the code that produces the `handout` file. We all agree that, once `\documentclass` has been parsed, `filename.pdf` is going to be produced no matter what. What my solution and yours do is to also create `filename_handout.pdf` by virtue of the `\write18` command. I am still trying the possibility of changing `\jobname` before `\documentclass`, so far without success.

Comment: @LMBC We both use \write18. I also provided facilities for within the source-code of the document forking depending on whether currently the main document or the handout is compiled. I have now added an example with a small package-file. Via the package-options you can in your document specify whether you additionally to <filename>.pdf wish to also have a handout <filename>_handout.pdf or not. Facilities for forking depending on whether the main document or the handout is to be compiled are available throughout the entire document which makes commenting/uncommenting bunches of code obsolete.